# How to run my ruby file in heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku

Sorry if i cannot make you understand, but this is how i understand and how i can tell you.
I am new to ruby and now i have learned a few and with that i have written a ruby code. It is actually to access the storageroom content management system from the form that i have done with ruby. And i used sinatra so i kept my stylesheet file in public folder and similarly i have a folder named storage_room_gem which i have to keep in the directory where my code is present.And another thing my code writes to a html file and it displays the html file.
Now i ran the code in my machine and it ran well. But i tried to run using heroku and it shows H10 error. what should i do?

Comment: H10 means **App crashed**. check heroku error log

Comment: I saw that error codes but cant find the way to rectify.Thankyou anyway.

Comment: If you edit your question with the error from the logs with the stacktrace, I'm sure someone could help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By issuing the command

```
heroku logs --app <your appname here>
```

you can see the logs. The error should be listed there, as well as the stacktrace. If you post that, it makes it easier to help debug your code. Here is a link to more information on the heroku logs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log_retrieval

Also, you can run it locally in a heroku-like environment using foreman. By running locally, you could have more tools at your disposal to investigate the error.

Here is a link to more information on foreman: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile/#developing_locally_with_foreman